# Change value of variable between components

Tags: angular, constructor

I'm trying to learn angular 4, I have a doubt with using variables for every component.

I have some routes like this:

```
const routes:Routes =[
    {path:'',component: HomeComponent,
 children: [
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
      { path: 'login',      component: LoginComponent    },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
  },
    //{path:'appcomponent',component:AppComponent},
    { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent }
];
```

The navigation (Routing) is good but I'm trying to hide and show the child components of "home" (welcome,users and login) and I cannot achieve it. 
In home component html I place:

```
<!-- body -->


<app-welcome *ngIf="hEW"  ></app-welcome>
<app-users *ngIf="hEU" ></app-users>
<app-login *ngIf="hEL"></app-login>

<!-- footer  -->
```

So in those three components I´m making something like:

```
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {

hEW = true;
hEU= false;
hEL = false;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

But these variables never take place in home.component.html , what should I do to make it work?  I'm more familiar with scope and rootscope than all this.

Comment: You're missing the whole point. The router injects the component of the current route next the the `<router-outlet>` directive. You shouldn't have app-welcome, app-users and app-login in the home component template. You should have router-outlet. This is fundamental router stuff. Read the documentation.

Comment: hi @JB Nizet  I need those components in my application, and maybe the routing could be better but is not related to this question

Comment: You are, once again, missing the point. Read my comment again. I'm not saying you don't need these components in your app. I'm saying that it's precisely the job of the router, thanks to router-outlet, to insert the right one automatically, based on the route definition. That's why you have `component: UsersComponent` in your users route: to tell the router that the UsersComponent is the one to display when the path is /users. So, again, you shouldn't have app-welcome, app-users and app-login **in the home component template**. You should have router-outlet instead.

Comment: My components have now this way:

 {path:'',component: AppComponent},
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
      { path: 'login',      component: LoginComponent  },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent }

Any idea why the AppComponent is duplicated when I visit  localhost:4200 ?

Comment: AppComponent have code like  <!-- nav bar codee -->  router-outlet   <!-- footer code -->

Comment: homeComponent was removed for this.... thnks jb again